# Зачем нужен queue основанный на deque?

Tags: c++, stl, очередь

Как известно, `queue` - это класс адаптер, в основе которого по умолчанию лежит `deque`. Все что делает `queue` - урезает функционал `deque`, вследствие чего у меня возникает вопрос об эффективности `queue` по умолчанию, ведь `deque` - это гибрид между двухсвязным списком и динамическим массивом, соответственно он обеспечивает вставку/извлечение данных в конец и произвольный доступ к данным с приемлемой скоростью, но не такой большой как у контейнеров со структурами данных предназначенными для отдельной задачи(list, vector), ведь это гибрид. Однако `queue` не поддерживает произвольный доступ, а значит `deque` в основе неэффективен.
Я узнал что структуру данных по умолчанию можно изменить на `list` или `vector`:

```
queue<char, list<char> > value;
```

Как по мне, `list` идеально подходит для основы очереди, но зачем нужна поддержка основ в виде вектора и деки(deque)?

P.S Уже сам понял что в каких ситуациях лучше использовать, помог в этом разобраться интересный [бенчмарк](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque.html). Лень писать ответ

Comment: Вектор это вектор, а дек, это очередь, разве нет?

Comment: @こきん, да, я имел ввиду очередь построенную по принципу FIFO, неправильно термины использовал, сейчас исправлю

Comment: если с очередью предполагается хоть какая то работа, то deque почти всегда эффективнее list. vector может быть хорош, на маленьких размерах. Но все покажет бенчмарк.

Comment: @KoVadim, ну насчет вектора при маленьких рамзерах соглашусь, возможно при удалении данных из начала легче будет перенести все элементы массива, чем создавать новый узел списка. Но вот в чём эффективность deque все равно не могу понять

Comment: deque - это список векторов. На самом деле, если в список много вставлять-удалять, то это очень тяжело для памяти. Во вторых, если в списке хранить просто целые числа, то накладные расходы будут просто огромные (нам нужно хранить как минимум два указателя, а это от 8 до 16 байт!!!)

Comment: хм, получается list как основа будет нужна при хранении в очереди больших структур данных типо каких-нибудь больших классов(например превышающих 16 байт)?

Comment: возможно. Но это все очень индивидуально. Я когда то экспериментировал в одном нагруженном проекте, где был список клиентов. Сам список - несколько тысяч элементов, меняется десятками в секунду. И вектор показал наиболее оптимально. Хотя изначально все предполагали другое. list хорош, если размеры велики и нужно делать операции по передаче куска с одно в другой - там это иногда за O(1) делается.